# How does stripe createToken verify that the card is not invalid?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

The error test cards only work when processing charge.

In a scenario where a bad card is successfully tokenized and the vendor-client transaction is processed (e.g. goods being sent), and then later the vendor needs to charge using the saved token but the charge fails, how can she protect herself against this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new card on a customer, Stripe automatically runs a $0/$1 authorization with the bank to make sure the card is valid and accepted. If the bank rejects the authorization, they will simply fail the card creation and return an error.

This allows you to catch expired or rejected cards upfront but it doesn't guarantee that future charges will succeed though even if the card is valid. The only way to confirm this is to charge the card and see what the bank responds.

In your situation, you'll want to charge the customer for the price of the goods before shipping anything. Once the charge succeeds, you're sure that you will get the funds.